# Force-Directed Graph, nodes are not moving and stuck in the center of the map

Tags: d3.js

I have a force graph where my nodes are actually a "g" element with an appended circle and an appended text element.

I am having trouble with my nodes as they do not move when dragged and are not positionned on the tip of the links.

If I change my nodes to simple circles only, then it works fine. But I am unable to get it to work with the "g" elements.

I have been suggested to use ".attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});" in my ticked() function since "g" element does not have cx and cy values (as those are specific to circles).

I think the problem comes from the way I create my drag() function.

Any help is more than welcome

[image]

```
  ForceGraph(){
    var links = [
        {src:"John",target:"Aurora"},
        {src:"John",target:"Mary"},
        {src:"John",target:"Erik"},
        {src:"John",target:"Susan"},
        {src:"John",target:"Mel"},
   ]

    var nodes = [
        {id:"John"},
        {id:"Aurora"},
        {id:"Mary"},
        {id:"Erik"},
        {id:"Susan"},
        {id:"Mel"},
    ]

    var width = this.$refs.mapFrame.clientWidth // scale to parent container
    var height = this.$refs.mapFrame.clientHeight // scale to parent container


    // Compute values.
    var nodeId = d => d.id // given d in nodes, returns a unique identifier (string)
    const N = d3.map(nodes, nodeId);
   const nodeTitle = (_, i) => N[i];
    const T = d3.map(nodes, nodeTitle);
    
    // Replace the input nodes and links with mutable objects for the simulation.
    nodes = nodes.map(n => Object.assign({}, n));
    links = links.map(l => ({
        orig: l,
        source: l.src,
        target: l.target
    }));
  

    // Construct the forces.
    const forceNode = d3.forceManyBody();
    const forceLink = d3.forceLink(links).id(({index: i}) => N[i]);
    forceNode.strength(-450);
    forceLink.strength(1);
    forceLink.distance(100)


    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
        .force(link, forceLink)
        .force("charge", forceNode)
        .force("x", d3.forceX())
        .force("y", d3.forceY())
        .on("tick", ticked);




    const svg = d3.create("svg")
    .attr("id", "svgId")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
        .attr("viewBox", [-width/2,-height/2, width,height])
        .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)



    const link = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(links)
        .join("line").attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", "5")
        ;



     var node = svg
        .selectAll(".circle-group")
        .data(nodes)
        .join(enter => {
          node = enter.append("g")        
            .attr("class", "circle-group")
            .call(drag(simulation));
          node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "background") 
            .style("fill", "blue")
            .attr("r", 30)
           // .call(drag(simulation));
          node.append("text")
            .attr("class", "foreground")
            .attr("dx", function(){return -20})
            .style('font-size', 30 * 0.4 + 'px')
            .text(({index: i}) => T[i])
           // .call(drag(simulation))
            
          node.attr("stroke", "grey"); 
        })
        node.call(drag(simulation));
        



    function ticked() {
        link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
        node
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});
       // .attr("cx", d => d.x)
       // .attr("cy", d => d.y);
    }


    function drag(simulation) {    
        function dragstarted(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
        }
        
        function dragged(event) {
        event.subject.fx = event.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.y;
        }
        
        function dragended(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        event.subject.fx = null;
        event.subject.fy = null;
        }

        return d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);
    }



    return  Object.assign(svg.node() );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `node` variable should be empty, which means you aren't updating anything in the tick function. Here's an abbreviated and isolated example of your join where I call `selection.size()` afterwards to see how many items are selected with `node`:

```js
var nodes = [1,2,3];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
     
var node = svg
   .selectAll(".circle-group")
   .data(nodes)
   .join(enter => {
       node = enter.append("g")        
         .attr("class", "circle-group")
       node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "background") 
            .style("fill", "blue")
            .attr("r", 30)
       node.append("text")
           
          node.attr("stroke", "grey"); 
})

console.log(node.size());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This is expected, the join returns the merged enter and update selections; however, since we are supplying a custom enter function we need to explicitly return the entered nodes (as we would also need to do if supplying a custom update function). From the docs:

> The selections returned by the enter and update functions are merged and then returned by selection.join

If we add `return node` to the end of your enter function we can see that our selection size is now 3.

```js
var nodes = [1,2,3];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
     
var node = svg
   .selectAll(".circle-group")
   .data(nodes)
   .join(enter => {
       node = enter.append("g")        
         .attr("class", "circle-group")
       node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "background") 
            .style("fill", "blue")
            .attr("r", 30)
       node.append("text")
           
          node.attr("stroke", "grey"); 
      return node;
})

console.log(node.size());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now as `node` includes the entered nodes, the tick function should work as intended.

An alternative would be to select the `g` elements every tick with `d3.select(".circle-group")` instead of using `node`, however, this isn't very performant.